# Anchor tag doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angular2-template

I have a string like this,

```
var str = '<a src="www.test/data">#data</a> time <a src="www.test/city">#city</a>';
```

I am using

```
 <div [innerHTML]="str">
```

It displays but ancholr links are not working.Can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Anchor supports `href` attribute not `src`, It has nothing to do with Angular. Also make sure URL has protocol mentioned like `http` or `https`.

```
<a href="http://www.test/data">#data</a> time <a href="http://www.test/city">#city</a>
```